# Prevent the use of VPN/SSH to bypass porn blocking solutions

Tags: router, firewall, opendns, web-filtering

I've read the various questions about content filtering and it seems that openDNS is the consensus solution, although it's easy to bypass with a VPN service or an SSH tunnel.  Is there a way to prevent that? Can the use of a specialized parental-control router (like SkyDog or iBoss) prevent bypassing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if traffic is encrypted, there is very little you can do to filter the traffic, because you cannot tell what it is. Any connection could be using one of many different protocols, and if it is encrypted you do not know which protocol it is using.

That said you can still try using an advanced router to block the standard ports that these services use, but there is no way of completely blocking someone from using alternate ports.

Comment: Well, you can always force HTTP (although some websites reject all http requests). Additionally, there's many ways of getting around HTTPS if you are an admin of the network, but modern webbrowsers will throw up a [warning page](http://askleowp.pugetsoundsoftwa.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/httpsaskleo.png) if you do this.